# Символы. String.fromCharCode()

Tags: javascript

```
 function switcher(x){
    var num = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var t = +x[i];
    num += String.fromCharCode(t);
   }
}

switcher(['24', '12', '23', '22', '4', '26', '9', '8']);
```

Доброго времени суток! При прохождении массива в цикле хочу из кода символов получить символ и добавить его в переменную num, но не могу понять почему этого не происходит. Помогите разобраться!

Comment: потому что ты забыл _return_ в функции, и она у тебя ничего не возвращает. Кроме того, все эти кода пробельных символов, то есть даже если ты вернешь строку, то увидишь в ней одни пробелы

Comment: А почему `num`, а не `result` или `str`? Был бы код побольше, кто-то мозг бы сломал: Отчего же переменная с таким названием is String?

Comment: @Grundy с return, все так же!

Comment: @Grundy странно, почему это кода пробельных символов и как сделать, что бы при возврате строки возвращались именно те символы у которых соответственный код в моей программе?

Comment: @Nick, Нет не так же, ведь надо было делать `return num;` после цикла.

Comment: _странно, почему это кода пробельных символов и как сделать, что бы при возврате строки возвращались именно те символы у которых соответственный код в моей программе?_ - ну так это и есть те символы, Например 9 - это код символа табуляции

Comment: @Grundy это получается, что число 24 и 12, 23, и т.д. имеют один и тотже символ? Как это так?

Comment: конечно они имеют разные символы, просто эти символы являются _пробельными_. То есть при печати их можно увидеть в виде пробела например.

Comment: @Grundy все я понял. Спасибо!